# Access Control to Azure Hosted App Service

Tags: azure, entra-id

We host an App Service in our tenant (xyz.onmicrosoft.com), and I am using Azure Identity services for authentication. I want to grant access to the application to users in another Azure tenant (customerxyz.onmirosoft.com).

One possibility is to invite each user as a Guest to our tenant individually. Then assign them access to the Enterprise application.

Ideally, I would like to control access to the Enterprise application using a group in the other Azure tenant (customerxyz.onmirosoft.com). Is this possible? What alternatives to the first approach do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built in authentication for app service, when used with AAD creates an Azure AD application for authentication, this is in your AAD tenant. The default option for this app is to allow only users from your AAD tenant. This would include guest users, so you could do as you say and invite users into your tenant.

You can switch the AAD app to be a "multi-tenant" application, this will let users from other AAD tenants into your application. However, this will let uses from **ANY** AAD tennant into your application, not just the one your are interested in. If you want to limit access to just the two tenants you would need to make some changes in your application code to check the tenant of the user and only allow in the ones you want. There is no functionlity in the App Service layer to do this for you.